# How to adjust contents to automatically fit size of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an requirement that an application(HTML, CSS and Javascript) should adjust automatically to screen window size - from laptops, to desktops to tablets. 
Does anyone know how can this be done?

Comment: You can't change the size of the browser but you can change the size of the contents inside. How to make the contents match depends on your existing HTML and CSS.

Comment: I dont want to change the size of the browser...i want to auto resize the contents inside so that the application opens up with the same display on any size of laptops desktops, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study Responsive Design.   But I'll tell you the big key: media queries.

With CSS like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #mydiv {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  #mydiv {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

you can do all you need.  In fact, for some screen sizes you can set #menu1 to display:none, and #menu2 to display:block, and thereby show entirely different layouts dynamically based on the screen size.

Try this link for a very minimal example you can play with
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_breakpoints